# Right way of data organasing and structuring

Tags: uri

I have the following structure of the site that is revealed in main menu hierarchy:

- News
  - news category 1
  - news category 2
- Documents
  - document category 1
  - document category 2

All the pages mostly will be presented with a single Content Type. But for different places in menu hierarchy page regions should consist of different blocks.

e.g., for a node from "news category 1" there will be a search block placed in the sidebar, for th enode from "document category 2" -- the login block.

I see a quite moot "solution" for this. I will have to turn nodes' urls into somewhat like "mysite.org/news/category1/..." and set visibility options to blocks through url patterns. Is it a right way to follow? But in this case the editor (not me) will have to invent and handcode url aliases when creating node and it seems to me very unreliable to entrust him with the site structure.

Another way -- create different content types for every categories and generate aliases automatically but it seems to me a bit crazy.

What do you think about that?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you'd like the editor to be able to add categories to the site and have them choose which blocks are shown for each category?

Comment: Exactly. Categories list is a certain and defined set and won't change. It'll be a menu hierarchy and editors will have to add node to one o another category. And nodes pages should have region stuffing appropriate to the category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your categories are pre-defined and won't change then I think your solution of using blocks regions and block visibility settings may be the best. If you need more complex visibility settings the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context/) module should be able to help.

Comment: Well, then the editor should write aliases every time the node is created?

Comment: If your URL structure was `news/cat1/nodetitle` then you could set the block visibility to only show certain blocks at the paths `news/cat1/*` (using `*` as a wildcard). When a new node was added to that category (and its URL was `news/cat1/nodetitle`) the same blocks would show. You would only have to set this up per category, rather than per node.

Comment: Well, maybe I've expressed badly but the problem for me is creating that `news/cat1/nodetitle`-like URL. Is this an editor's duty to enter aliases in?

Comment: [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) is the module you are looking for in that case. You can set up patterns at Admin > Configuration > URL Aliases that set how the automatic URLs will be filled.